# How to I grep unique occurrences across multiple files?

Tags: recursion, count, grep, unique

I want to grep across multiple files and display the unique and count of the results. For example:

```
filea:
text1
text2
text3

fileb:
text1
text3

filec:
text2
text3

grep -r "text*" ???

output:
text1 2
text2 2
text3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk '/text/{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file*
```

I haven't tested, but it should go.